# URL rewrite 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Original url :  `mydomain/index.php?lang=english`
   I want url   :  `mydomain/english`

My .htaccess file below :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

But I get 500 internal server error. How can I solved this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really have there dashes?

Comment: Use `RewriteLog /tmp/rewrite.log` or show us at least `error.log`

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ ?lang=$1 [L] # and maybe QSA too
```

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite engine loops until the URI stops changing. Try adding some conditions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I try but it is still origin url